# Recommended way to test Python extensions written in X language

Tags: python, testing, pyo3

I have some `class A` that is part of a Python extension I wrote in Rust using PyO3. `class A` is imported and used as is, as well as being as being subclassed in my Python code as part of a larger Python package. It's not meant to be an independent Rust library.

I want to make tests for `class A` but I'm not sure if tests should be written in Rust, in Python or both.

What's the recommended way for testing Python extensions written in another language like Rust?

Comment: Without more details it is hard to decide. Ask yourself this: in which programming language is your code going to be used in? Are you going to be writing Rust code used by other bits inside your program/library that's also written in Rust? If the answer is both Python and Rust, chances are it would be beneficial to write tests for both languages.

Comment: @metatoaster It's for a python package im writing. It's not meant to be a Rust library.

Comment: Just stick with the standard python `unittest` module, and see if that address your needs.  Again without more specific details there will be no concrete answers, and it's up to you to figure out whether this approach works/fit for the purposes of your project.